# Gulp not working after downgrade

Tags: javascript, gulp, downgrade

After installing `gulp#4` (the next version of gulp `npm install 'gulpjs/gulp.git#4.0' --save-dev` ) I was doing a couple of tests and ended up going to the last version but the console kept printing me the following output `AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified` I've tried several things like changing branch, removing the `node_modules` and installing a different gulp version like gulp@3 but none work

```
$ npm run watch

> cx-content-extractor@0.0.1 watch /Users/alevale/work/CLIENT
> gulp watch

assert.js:60
  throw new errors.AssertionError({
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (/Users/alevale/work/CLIENT/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (/Users/alevale/work/CLIENT/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
    at /Users/alevale/work/CLIENT/gulpfile.js:43:10
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alevale/work/CLIENT/gulpfile.js:168:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cx-content-extractor@0.0.1 watch: `gulp watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the cx-content-extractor@0.0.1 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alevale/.npm/_logs/2017-07-20T12_28_19_935Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanna share my silly mistake ^^

After a couple of tries it seemed like the changes I did were saved in the `package-lock.json` and I forgot to delete that file as well when getting the environment in a "clean state"